# Como concatenar utilizando StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string

Tengo el siguiente metodo toString de una clase

```
public String toString(){
   return  "Solicitud [idSolicitud=" + idSolicitud +", numCifra=" + numCifra +", usuarioBD=" + usuarioBD +"]";

}
```

y lo que quiero es concatenar con StringBuilder, dicen que es mejor practica, pero como se hace?
gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esa concatenación echa con StringBuilder seria de la siguiente forma:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int idSolicitud = 300;
        double numCifra = 3.14;
        char usuarioBD = 'A';

        // Creas un nuevo StringBuilder.
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        // Agregas los String o Variables al builder con append
        builder.append("Solicitud [idSolicitud="); //String
        builder.append(idSolicitud); // Var
        builder.append(", numCifra=");
        builder.append(numCifra);
        builder.append(", usuarioBD=");
        builder.append(usuarioBD);
        builder.append("]");

        // Conviertes a string
        String result = builder.toString();

        // Print result.
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

---

### Algunos métodos útiles:

**`append()`** se utiliza para ir agregando diferentes objetos a tu Builder, siempre al final, como una cola.

---

**`insert()`** se utiliza para agregar un objeto o substring en la posición especificada.

```
// Inserta un substring en la posición 2.
builder.insert(2, "xyz");
```

---

**`indexOf()`** se utiliza para intentar encontrar la posición de el elemento que le envías. Devuelve `-1` si no existe.

```
// Intenta encontrar la posición del substring.
int result = builder.indexOf("bc");
```

---

**`delete()`** se utiliza para borrar el contenido del Builder entre dos posiciones.

```
// Borra los characteres desde el index 2 hasta el index 5.
builder.delete(2, 5);
```

---

**`toString()`** genera el string de tu Builder, según que contenga.

```
String result = builder.toString();
```

---

**`substring()`** genera el string a partir de una posición y del largo deseado (parámetro opcional)

```
// Toma un substring despues de los 2 primeros characteres.
String omitFirstTwo = builder.substring(2);
System.out.println(omitFirstTwo);

// Toma solo los 2 primeros characteres. 
String firstTwo = builder.substring(0, 2); // 0 posición - 2 longitud
System.out.println(firstTwo);
```

---

> Puedes encontrar mas información en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Gracias , me ayudo bastante!